# Initialize collection and property of collection

Tags: c#

If I subclassed list, and added a property...

```
class MyList : List<MyType>
{
    public int MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

or

```
class MyCollection<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    public int MyProperty {get;set;}
}
```

I can initialize the property:

```
var l = new MyList() {MyProperty = 1};
```

Or I can initialize the list:

```
var m = new MyList() {new MyType(),new MyType()};
```

Can I initialize both the list and properties of the list?

Comment: Deriving from a `List<T>` is usually the wrong approach.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt

Comment: Why not derive from `IEnumerable<T>` or even `ICollection<T>`? Usually the collection classes implement interfaces as mentioned.

Comment: @TheGeneral - This is not exactly my implementation.  I'm just using this example for illustration purposes.  I just want to know if it is possible to initialize a collection and a property at the same time.